# Prompt doesn't scroll/clear until window resizing (using gdb/cgdb in bash)

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, gdb

I'm just learning to write C, and I have been having this problem while using `gdb`/`cgdb`. It's really annoying, to the extent that it discourages me from using the debugger entirely. I'm using WSL for my terminal, and this happens in both local/ssh environments.

The problem: 
When I launch `cgdb`/`gdb` (in the images without any files passed in, but doesn't matter), I get

[image: IMG1]

The issue is at the last line. It doesn't give me any clean space to write commands.

When I type something (I wrote `abcdefghi`), it gets written on top of the last line as if you're doing "insert" like this:

[image: IMG2]

But then if I manually resize my terminal window even by a few pixels horizontally or vertically, the last line shifts to what should have looked like at the first place:

[image: IMG3]

And the same issue happens again with the `abcdefghi` I wrote when I try putting in another command.

I tried searching around and I could not locate where the issue is coming from. I checked `shopt | grep checkwinsize` and confirmed that it's on. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will do the job only very temporarily, because soon as I write another command same issue happens.

Please help me locate the issue / fix it. Much appreciated!

Comment: i am having the same issue.  Did you ever find out a solution?